# Image not fitting in Circular background in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am following [this](http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/android-material-design-profile-screen-xml-ui-design.html) article:

As can be seen below, my image, does not fit into the circular background I have given my ImageView.  I can see the circular background, but the image does not fit into it.

[image]

Here is my `@drawable/circular_border` style:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="100dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
<stroke
    android:width="3dip"
    android:color="#f9f9f9" />
<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" />
```

Here is my layout code:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePlaceHolder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_border"
            android:imageBitmap="@{user._profileImageEncoded}" />
```

Here is the imageBitmap BindingAdapter I am using to set the Bitmap to the ImageView.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:imageBitmap")
public static void SetImageBitmap(ImageView view, String bsae64EncodedString){
    if (bsae64EncodedString == null){
        view.setImageBitmap(null);
    }else{
        byte[] imageBytes = Base64.decode(bsae64EncodedString, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        view.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

How do I get the image to display in the circle?

Comment: can you post your code of where you call the image ? also, its gonna be easy for you using a library for it  like this one https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: yes but the drawable xml file is a style for the imageView , with shapes @SahdevRajput74

Comment: @GastónSaillén I have updated my code to show the BindingAdapter that sets the ImageView

Comment: can you share @drawable/circular_border ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén Added it, although it is the same as in the article...

Comment: i would suggest using src and not background , can you change it ? android:src="......"

Comment: @android_monstertjie preview it willnot show circle image...test it real device once..

Comment: `@drawable/circular_border` is not a valid xml. You are missing the closing `Shape` tag

Comment: @RobertEstivill It is valid, I just did not paste the closing </shape> tag, left it out by accident.

Comment: @GastónSaillén Changed the src to point to drawable, did not make a difference

Comment: @GowthamanM Why will it work on real device, and not on emulator?